# MongoEngine version supporting mongoDB 3.0

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

Which version of mongoengine has started supporting MongoDB v3.0?

MongoDB v3.0 compatibility is mentioned only in the documentation of latest version - [v0.15.0](https://pypi.org/project/mongoengine/).

My current mongoengine version is `v0.8.7`.

Comment: I don't think there is anything really in the MongoEngine codebase itself that needed to change for that version. The only real "new feature" things were actually introduced with MongoDB 3.4 and 3.6 in terms of "underlying driver" implementation, and that should really depend on the installed `pymongo` instead. Is there something specific you have a problem with? The documentation on that project likely has not been updated for some time.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Neil. I was wondering if there is anything mongodb v3.0 specific that needs to be considered while deciding which version of mongoengine to upgrade to. I don't want to jump directly to v0.15.0 from v0.8.7. And mongoengine documentation mentions support of MongoDB v3.0 directly in v0.15.0, it left me wondering if earlier versions don't support MongoDB v3.0.

Comment: The only big issue would be around authentication mechanisms. But again, that's an "underlying driver" issue more than anything. So again, that's not really "directly" related to mongoengine itself.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thank you. That'll help a lot.

Comment: @NeilLunn Just a confirmation question, if I upgrade mongoDB to 3.0 while mongoengine stays at 0.8.7, I should not expect any sort of exception/error, right?

Comment: What are your versions of MongoDB server and PyMongo? MongoEngine hasn't kept up with the latest [PyMongo API changes](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/migrate-to-pymongo3.html) and all of the server versions noted as tested (2.4, 2.6, and 3.0) are now End-of-Life and no longer supported or updated by MongoDB. You can check the [Python Driver Compatibility matrix](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/driver-compatibility-reference/#python-driver-compatibility) for a recommended version of PyMongo to match your server version, but it's likely that MongoEngine will need some patches.